# Mouswheel with one page navi - scroll only at the end of section

Tags: javascript, mousewheel

I had onepageNav script to scrollTo pages. Pages it's not full height of window than i had problem with addition mousewhell.

I had code:

```
          $('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
          if (flag) { return false; }
          $current = $('section.current');

          if (delta > 0) {
              $prev = $current.prev();

              if ($prev.length) {
                  flag = true;
                  $('body').scrollTo($prev, 1000, {
                      onAfter : function(){
                          flag = false;
                      }
                  });
                  $current.removeClass('current');
                  $prev.addClass('current');
              }
          } else {
              $next = $current.next();

              if ($next.length) {
                  flag = true;
                  $('body').scrollTo($next, 1000, {
                      onAfter : function(){
                          flag = false;
                      }
                  });
                  $current.removeClass('current');
                  $next.addClass('current');
              }
          }

          event.preventDefault();
      });
```

It's script for mousewheel. It's work but not exacly what i want.
If i had section #2 bigger than window than it's go automaticaly after scroll to next section.
I i had section #3 last, bigget than windows and i scroll down than scrolling stop working.

Someone had idea how to resolve that?

Comment: It's hard to say something without demo, but it's obvious that you don't check section height anywhere. I think you should compare container height and a section height, and if section's height more than container's height then not to preventDefault of the scroll.

Comment: I think about that, but i don't have any idea how to check section height. or where we are now. I know how to check height of some section, but what with that i need to do?

Comment: Post your HTML code and we'll be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use the following code:

HTML:

```
<section id='s1'></section>
<section id='s2'></section>
<section id='s3'></section>
<section id='s4'></section>
```

JS:

```
function elementInViewport2(el) {
  var top = el.offsetTop;
  var left = el.offsetLeft;
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var height = el.offsetHeight;

  while(el.offsetParent) {
    el = el.offsetParent;
    top += el.offsetTop;
    left += el.offsetLeft;
  }

  return (
    top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
    left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
    (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
    (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
  );
};

var current = $('section').first();
current.addClass('current');
var flag;

$(window).scroll(function(event, delta) {
    if (flag) { return false; }

    var $body = $('body'),
        $window = $(window),
        newScroll = $body.scrollTop();

    if (!elementInViewport2(current[0])) {
        current.removeClass('current');
        current[0] = null;
    }

    var newSection = $('section:not(.current)').filter(function(i, el) {
        return elementInViewport2(el);
    }).first();

    if (newSection[0] && current[0] != newSection[0]) {
        current.removeClass('current');
        current = newSection;
        newSection.addClass('current');
        flag = true;
        $body.animate({scrollTop: newSection.offset().top}, function() {
            flag = false;
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8dMG/2/)